# Formula to Extract Duplicates in Two Columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've got a large amount of data that I need to analyse. Two of the columns contain values that I need to check for duplicates that will look something like this:

```
1    A
1    B
1    A
2    A
2    B
2    B
3    C
3    C
3    C
3    A
```

So the formula run across two columns would ideally spit out:

```
1    A
1    B
2    A
2    B
3    A
3    C
```

I've been using the following to extract duplicates from a single column, but am lost when it comes to looking at two columns.

```
{=INDEX(ImportedData!$C$2:$C$500,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($L$1:L1,ImportedData!$C$2:$C$500),0))}
```

Unfortunately I want to avoid manipulating the reference data, so it really makes things difficult. I'm thinking of concatenating the two columns and checking that singular column for dupes, but I feel like there's got to be a better way and suspect that doing that may also cause issues down the road.

Comment: copy and paste the columns then use Remove Duplicates it is on the Data tab.

Comment: Use the Advanced Filter with Unique Records Only, Copy to another location.  Then sort the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **C1** enter:

```
=A1 & B1
```

and copy downwards.  In **D1** enter `1`, in **D2** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($C$1:C2,C2)>1,"",1+MAX($D$1:D1))
```

and copy downwards.  Column **D** marks each unique data pair.

In **E1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(ROW(),D:D,0)),"")
```

and copy downwards.  In **F1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(ROW(),D:D,0)),"")
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

Comment: Had to make a tiny adjustment of adding -1 to Row() to account for headers, but worked wonderfully. Thanks!

Comment: @Tock  you are quite welcome!